# Give developer access to part of repo by using git submodules?

Tags: git-submodules

I have a repository and I need work done by some subcontractors, let's say.
Instead of splitting the repo up into dependencies, to hide proprietary code, I can easily put all of the non-sensitive code in a folder, and somehow just give the subcontractors access to this one folder. Is this a good use case for `git submodules`? If so, what might the workflow look like exactly?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Nohow** just give the subcontractors access to this one folder. Git doesn't operate on the level of subtree
2. Submodules is bad choice, consider subtree
3. Both submodules|subtree mount as subfolder *external independent repo*, thus you have to split original repo anyway

Comment: can you elaborate on point #2 in the comments?

Comment: @AlexanderMills - easy: https://www.google.com/search?q=why+you+shouldn%E2%80%99t+use+Git+submodules